# Count values in a dataframe column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator

I have a column in a dataframe that looks something like this

```
0                                                   NaN
1                                              ["arts"]
2                                       ["sports", "tech"]
3     ["arts", "finance", "health", "sports", "science"...
4                            ["finance", "sports", "tech"]
5                    ["arts", "finance", "sports", "tech"]
6     ["arts", "finance", "health", "sports", "science"...
7                            ["arts", "sports", "science"]
```

I would love to know how many times Arts occured across all these lists of lists. However, upon trying out `column.explode().value_counts(sort=True)` I just get a basic distribution with options which is not what I want.

```
["tech"]                                                   5
["arts", "finance", "sports", "tech"]                         2
["arts", "sports"]                                            2
["finance", "sports"]                                         1
["arts"]                                                   1
```

I even tried using counters `collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(v.split(',') for v in column))` but I get the following error `'float' object has no attribute 'split'`

Any pointers?

Comment: Why did you said "lists of lists"? You just have a col with a list in every row right?

Comment: Yes thats what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

If `column` is not too long, a simple nested loop should work just fine:

```
count = 0
for str_list in column:
    for name in str_list:
        if name == "arts":
            count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: This works for valid rows, but will throw something like "'float' object is not iterable' when trying to iterate over a row whose value in the column is NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask of rows that contain arts by doing something like:

```
mask = df['industry'].apply(lambda x: 'comedy' in x)
```

And then restrict your dataframe to your new mask

```
df = df[mask]
```

From there you should just be able to use len(df) or something like that.

If the industry you are looking for can appear more than once in each row, you could use your itertools idea. The float error comes from trying to split a NaN, so make sure to use dropna() before you try and concatenate the lists.

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df['industry'].dropna().values)).count('arts')
```

Comment: len(df) only returns the number of rows in which 'comedy' (in your example) appears, I believe the OP wants the total number of times 'comedy' (or 'arts' or whatever) appear in the column

Comment: @danie true, though it appears that each genre only appears once per row. But on the chance it appears more than once, I added a solution using the itertools idea. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Ah so the problem is I want an output similar to values_counts. So for example, Arts 10, Science 5...etc instead of me having to provide that.

Comment: @zeroanthem86 list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df['industry'].dropna().values)) gives you a exploded list of your industry column, so there are lots of methods you could use from there to count, for example: all_industries = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df['industry'].dropna().values)), then for unique_industry in set(all_industries): ..... something like that. Could do it in one line with a list comprehension.